# cannot find buffer error in aws-mobile-ionic-sample

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic3

I am Installing IONIC Project in aws. They provided one starter for configuration. The link is:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-ionic-sample

I cloned it when I am running "Ionic serve" command. I am facing below Issue. please help me fix it. It was showing

> Typescript Error Cannot find name 'Buffer'

Errors

[image: Please check this screenshot for more Info]